# How to calculate a chi square for this data set?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

This is my data set called mother.

```
 bodymass       pregnant
  28.5            yes
  33.3            no
  23.4            yes
  26.6            no
  34.1            no 
  26.4            yes
  45.6            no
  25.3            yes
  25.5            no
  24              yes
```

I want to calculate the hypothesis for this through a chi square test. So i set my hypothesis like this:

> $H_0$: There is no relation between bmi and pregnant.
>
> $H_1$: There is a relation between bmi and pregnant.

The codes I've tried:

```
dfd<- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2))
dfd[,1]<- mother$bodymass
dfd[,2]<- mother$pregnant
header<- c('bodymass', 'pregnant')
colnames(dfd)<- header
dfd
chisq.test(dfd)
```

But I got error which says:

> Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Please suggest the solution. Also suggest what other test can we for this problem besides t test.

Comment: Use `as.factor(mother$pregnant)` to change to a `factor` variable, that should solve the specific error. Note that Chi2 test is used with contingency tables(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test), you don't use it with continuous variables, as far as I know. I'd suggest a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RLave said in the comments you have a continuous and a categorical variable. For chi square test you need two categorical variables. What you can do with your data is basically comparing means.

The best way for your small data set would be the Mann-Whitney-U-Test:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
bodymass       pregnant
28.5            yes
33.3            no
23.4            yes
26.6            no
34.1            no 
26.4            yes
45.6            no
25.3            yes
25.5            no
24              yes", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

wilcox.test(bodymass ~ pregnant, data = df, alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  bodymass by pregnant
W = 22, p-value = 0.05556
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Will this test work if i have a 500 rows of data instead of only 10?

Comment: Yes it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @Humpelstielzchen answer that a (little) graphical representation goes a long way.

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(df, aes(pregnant, bodymass, color = pregnant)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_beeswarm()
```

[image: Boxplot]

The variabilities in the two groups are very different!

Comment: But this graphics suggests that there is a difference when the test is saying the opposite, doesn't it? Using the standard threshold of 0.05.

Comment: One of the conclusions of the tests is that you do not have enough data to conclude that the two groups are different. And I also kind of see that in the graph...

Comment: @RLave, thanks for the additional comment.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, thanks for the additional comment.

Answer (score 0):

Besides t-test you can use Welch test. Besides Mann-Whitney test you can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: @GBlondel, Thanks for the answer.